# Access files stored on Android smartphone from Windows

Tags: windows, android

Is there any way to get access to files that are stored within the memory of an Android-based smartphone (HTC Wildfire; Android 2.2.1) using Windows 7? After connecting the phone to computer, I'm only able to see files stored on the memory card. If possible, I'd prefer not to install anything on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyPhoneExplorer is the answer. The file-manager isn't the best one, but still allows to view files. I had to install not only PC-app, but also an app from Google Play, but still it did give me what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you install the driver package from HTC you probably get a special device in you "My Computer" where you can see multiple separate storage locations on the same phone. Like the SD and the internal storage.

Comment: I've already forgot HTC has a windows program for smartphone management :/. I'll check it in a minute

Comment: Nope, HTC Sync doesn't even want to connect to the phone

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ADB Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbbrowser/)

For this browser to work you probably need to have the HTC USB drivers install and "USB Debugging" needs to be enabled in the "Developer" section of the settings on your HTC.

Comment: Looks nice, I'll try it later (although I already used MyPhoneExplorer)